# AMOS: CFA testing invariance, but cannot name intercepts

Tags: confirmatory-factor, intercept, amos, invariance

I'm using AMOS to run a 2-factor model with 5 indicators each (10 in total). I'm assessing the invariance. So I'm assessing the invariance for sex. While the configural  and metric invariance worked fine. I'm unable to assess scalar invariance. I was able to name the factor loadings, which fixed them to be equal across sex groups. However, when I try to assess the scalar invariance by fixing the intercepts the window remains gray. The box for naming the intercepts is unclickable. Does anybody know a fix?
[image: Picture of the amos interface]

Answer (score 0):

You must estimate means and intercepts in your model in order to select these. Choose this option in analysis properties.